# My Text input is resizing automatically when i clicked on it

Tags: react-native

```
      render() {
    return (

      <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection:'column',justifyContent:'space-evenly',alignItems:'center',backgroundColor:datum.secondaryColor}}>

      <TextInput
        placeholderTextColor={datum.secondaryColor}
        style={{

          height: '7%', borderColor:datum.primaryColor, borderWidth: 1,
          width:'50%',backgroundColor:datum.primaryColor, fontWeight: '200'
        }}

         onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({name:value})}
        placeholder="Name"

      />
      <TextInput
      placeholderTextColor={datum.secondaryColor}
        style={{height: '7%', borderColor:datum.primaryColor, borderWidth: 1,width:'50%',backgroundColor:datum.primaryColor, fontWeight: '200'}}
        onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({number:value})}
          placeholder="Mobile no"

      />

      <Button

        onPress={()=>this.signupPressed()
        }
       title="Signup"
        color={datum.primaryColor}
       accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
/>

      </View>
    );
  }
```

[image: Image When I about to click the text input:]
[image: Image when i clicked the text input]

actually, I am designing a simple form page, I am struggling while handling keyboard, Yes I have also seen react native docs, in that they have suggested me to use Keyboardavoiding view but that makes the layout even worse so, can anyone tell how to handle the issue

Comment: May be it is happening because of borderwidhth.Please try and remove that.May be it help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im think the virtual keyboard is affecting your width and height, instead of using percentages for your width and height, you can try using dimensions:

```
var windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width; 
var windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height; 

width: width * 0.5
height: height * 0.07
```

Comment: What is the role for dimesnions here ?